# Sticky Nav after header is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't understand why this isn't working. I am trying to make this navigation stick to the top once the user has scrolled the height of the header.

http://jsfiddle.net/fq8ebw6x/

There is the JSfiddle and it is doing what I want however when I copy and paste the code into my document the nav doesn't become fixed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

```js
var mn = $(".nav");
mns = "nav-scrolled";
hdr = $('header').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > hdr) {
    mn.addClass(mns);
  } else {
    mn.removeClass(mns);
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  background: url("images/main-banner.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 940px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav,
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.nav-scrolled,
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.default-bg {
  background: #ffffff;
  background: url("images/body-bg.jpg");
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav {
  background: url("images/nav-bg.png");
  height: 87px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.20);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.20);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.20);
  z-index: 150;
}
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <title>Hello</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/sticky-nav.js"></script>
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
  </header>

  <nav class="nav">
    <a href="#">Nav Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Nav Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Nav Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Nav Link 4</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="default-bg">

    <div class="container">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean fringilla, purus in porttitor pellentesque, erat arcu tincidunt diam, dapibus faucibus leo mauris at sapien. In porttitor vehicula sodales. Vivamus massa neque, facilisis eu felis ut,
        aliquet convallis nisi. Nam elementum tellus vitae gravida fermentum. Nullam et imperdiet leo. Integer ut euismod lorem, in placerat lacus. Curabitur bibendum arcu ut feugiat commodo. Suspendisse ut mi vel orci ullamcorper tincidunt. Nam vitae
        fringilla nibh. Nullam hendrerit blandit velit eu hendrerit.</p>

      <p>Praesent eu enim non massa pellentesque lobortis. In in sagittis dolor. Aliquam non massa erat. Ut aliquet gravida tellus, sed volutpat nibh condimentum et. Nunc quam purus, vehicula quis venenatis et, porttitor vel dolor. Cras facilisis dui id
        elit bibendum, in ullamcorper leo ultricies. Praesent rutrum lacus sit amet sem convallis, ut interdum dolor vestibulum.</p>

      <p>Tum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In iaculis pharetra odio, sit amet consectetur elit facilisis ac. Praesent eget tristique ipsum. Donec malesuada bibendum lacinia. Praesent non purus sodales,
        pulvinar mi vitae, tincidunt leo. Phasellus vitae elit ut nisl semper fringilla id rutrum dolor. Donec a massa adipiscing, cursus risus vitae, porttitor tortor. Nullam sagittis est sapien, sit amet pharetra turpis imperdiet vel. Etiam sit amet
        ligula pretium, vulputate eros ac, bibendum velit. Aenean convallis ante purus, ac bibendum orci laoreet ac. Donec a convallis mauris. Nulla non lacus non ipsum pretium tempor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean at ipsum vulputate, sagittis
        dui ut, pharetra neque. Nam eget sodales orci. Aliquam pharetra nunc at nisl pellentesque, nec fringilla enim iaculis.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean fringilla, purus in porttitor pellentesque, erat arcu tincidunt diam, dapibus faucibus leo mauris at sapien. In porttitor vehicula sodales. Vivamus massa neque, facilisis eu felis ut,
        aliquet convallis nisi. Nam elementum tellus vitae gravida fermentum. Nullam et imperdiet leo. Integer ut euismod lorem, in placerat lacus. Curabitur bibendum arcu ut feugiat commodo. Suspendisse ut mi vel orci ullamcorper tincidunt. Nam vitae
        fringilla nibh. Nullam hendrerit blandit velit eu hendrerit.</p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean fringilla, purus in porttitor pellentesque, erat arcu tincidunt diam, dapibus faucibus leo mauris at sapien. In porttitor vehicula sodales. Vivamus massa neque, facilisis eu felis ut,
        aliquet convallis nisi. Nam elementum tellus vitae gravida fermentum. Nullam et imperdiet leo. Integer ut euismod lorem, in placerat lacus. Curabitur bibendum arcu ut feugiat commodo. Suspendisse ut mi vel orci ullamcorper tincidunt. Nam vitae
        fringilla nibh. Nullam hendrerit blandit velit eu hendrerit.</p>

      <p>Praesent eu enim non massa pellentesque lobortis. In in sagittis dolor. Aliquam non massa erat. Ut aliquet gravida tellus, sed volutpat nibh condimentum et. Nunc quam purus, vehicula quis venenatis et, porttitor vel dolor. Cras facilisis dui id
        elit bibendum, in ullamcorper leo ultricies. Praesent rutrum lacus sit amet sem convallis, ut interdum dolor vestibulum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean fringilla, purus in porttitor pellentesque, erat arcu tincidunt diam, dapibus faucibus leo mauris at sapien. In porttitor vehicula sodales. Vivamus massa neque, facilisis eu felis ut,
        aliquet convallis nisi. Nam elementum tellus vitae gravida fermentum. Nullam et imperdiet leo. Integer ut euismod lorem, in placerat lacus. Curabitur bibendum arcu ut feugiat commodo. Suspendisse ut mi vel orci ullamcorper tincidunt. Nam vitae
        fringilla nibh. Nullam hendrerit blandit velit eu hendrerit.</p>

      <p>Praesent eu enim non massa pellentesque lobortis. In in sagittis dolor. Aliquam non massa erat. Ut aliquet gravida tellus, sed volutpat nibh condimentum et. Nunc quam purus, vehicula quis venenatis et, porttitor vel dolor. Cras facilisis dui id
        elit bibendum, in ullamcorper leo ultricies. Praesent rutrum lacus sit amet sem convallis, ut interdum dolor vestibulum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean fringilla, purus in porttitor pellentesque, erat arcu tincidunt diam, dapibus faucibus leo mauris at sapien. In porttitor vehicula sodales. Vivamus massa neque, facilisis eu felis ut,
        aliquet convallis nisi. Nam elementum tellus vitae gravida fermentum. Nullam et imperdiet leo. Integer ut euismod lorem, in placerat lacus. Curabitur bibendum arcu ut feugiat commodo. Suspendisse ut mi vel orci ullamcorper tincidunt. Nam vitae
        fringilla nibh. Nullam hendrerit blandit velit eu hendrerit.</p>

      <p>Praesent eu enim non massa pellentesque lobortis. In in sagittis dolor. Aliquam non massa erat. Ut aliquet gravida tellus, sed volutpat nibh condimentum et. Nunc quam purus, vehicula quis venenatis et, porttitor vel dolor. Cras facilisis dui id
        elit bibendum, in ullamcorper leo ultricies. Praesent rutrum lacus sit amet sem convallis, ut interdum dolor vestibulum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean fringilla, purus in porttitor pellentesque, erat arcu tincidunt diam, dapibus faucibus leo mauris at sapien. In porttitor vehicula sodales. Vivamus massa neque, facilisis eu felis ut,
        aliquet convallis nisi. Nam elementum tellus vitae gravida fermentum. Nullam et imperdiet leo. Integer ut euismod lorem, in placerat lacus. Curabitur bibendum arcu ut feugiat commodo. Suspendisse ut mi vel orci ullamcorper tincidunt. Nam vitae
        fringilla nibh. Nullam hendrerit blandit velit eu hendrerit.</p>

      <p>Praesent eu enim non massa pellentesque lobortis. In in sagittis dolor. Aliquam non massa erat. Ut aliquet gravida tellus, sed volutpat nibh condimentum et. Nunc quam purus, vehicula quis venenatis et, porttitor vel dolor. Cras facilisis dui id
        elit bibendum, in ullamcorper leo ultricies. Praesent rutrum lacus sit amet sem convallis, ut interdum dolor vestibulum.</p>
   
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe you are not running it ondomready. wrap your js in $(function(){/*your js here*/});

Comment: Nah that didn't work. :(

Comment: got jquery on the page? Getting any console errors?

Comment: No console errors and I just edited my html in the original post to show my Jquery linked to the page.

Comment: sticky-nav.js is in your header, but $('header') hasn't been created yet so it has no height. I thought the $(function(){/*your js here*/}); would have fixed it but you say it didn't. Could you try putting the Javascript under the <header>?

Comment: Wow! I get it now. Always forget that these documents get read from top to bottom. Moving the JS to the footer worked perfectly! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Or you could just wrap it using `$()`.